# Disable “application has stopped working” window

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a .NET WCF service that should be 100% uptime ideally, But sometimes we have a memory leaking issues in our application that caused by 3rd party DB connectivity component which causes the service to crash.

We configured nnCron to watch for the service process and restart the service if it isn't running, but when the program crashes Windows displays this dialog box

[image]

The process nnCron is watching still exists until we click `Close the program`, which keeps nnCron from restarting the service.

Is there a way to disable this dialog box?

Comment: Note that if it is *your* application, the better approach would be to deal with that in the code (e.g. monitor the memory usage of some structures and end the process gracefully if they grow too big) instead of waiting for the kernel to kill it.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage this in Group Policy.

1. Go to **Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Windows Error Reporting**.
2. Find the policy **Prevent display of the user interface for critical errors**. Here, the Local Group Policy Editor is shown. You may also use Group Policy Management if you are in a domain.
   [image]
3. Change the policy setting to **Enabled**.
   [image]
4. (In a domain) Apply the policy object to all appropriate computers/groups.

You may also wish to **Disable Windows Error Reporting** entirely. In addition to using Group Policy, you can [disable Windows Error Reporting via Server Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754364.aspx#BKMK_disableWER_RMT).